# Is there a way to get the fts stream data back from the parsed data we get from the fts stream?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

As the output of the export items Api in EWS, we are able to get data in the form of fts stream, which can be parsed using outlook spy to get the data, is it possible to get the fts stream back from the parsed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTS format is not documented. You can try to hack the data: it is really not very complicated - a stream of serialized MAPI properties with page breaks every 32k or so, but the format has never been documented.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am is author) is an option, it supports exporting and importing FTS data through `RDOMail.SaveAs` and `RDOMail.Import` - you can create an MSG file using `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile`, then import FTS data using `RDOMail.Import(..., olFts)`

Comment: i have the set of properties in the form of PR_ENTRY ID: ( the value) im wondering if i can convert it back to the fts form ( it just seems complicated)

Comment: In theory, yes, you can - FTS stream is exactly that - property vs value stream. I don't know of any products that would you do that, you'd need to create your own solution for that. In Redemption, you can create a standalone MSG file using `RDOSession.CreateMessagerFromMsgFile`, set properties one at a time using `RDOMail.Fields`, then save it as an FTS stream using `RDOMail.SaveAs(..., olFts)`.